# How does one compare a Fraction object to an integer?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to operator overloading and I don't clearly understand how to compare a Fraction object to an integer. I ran a test of assert(FractionOb < 0) == false and I was given an assertion error. How do I design a lt method that will compare the fraction to an integer?

`

class Fraction:
    def **init**(self,numerator=0,denominator=1):
        '''
        Initializes the Fraction to the numerator and denominator
        values provided by the constructor.

```
    numerator - value of numerator with a default value of 0.
                The type must be of integer.
    denomenator - value of denomenator with a default value of 1.
                  The type must be of integer.
    '''
    if not isinstance(denominator,int):
        raise TypeError("denominator must be of type int!")
    if not isinstance(numerator,int):
        raise TypeError("numerator must be of type int!")
    if denominator == 0:
        raise ZeroDivisionError("Denominator cannot be 0")
    self.numer = numerator
    self.denom = denominator
    self.normalize()

def __str__(self):
    s = "%d /% d" % (self.numer,self.denom)
    return s

def normalize(self):
    reduce = Fraction.gcd(self.numer, self.denom)
    self.numer = self.numer // reduce
    self.denom = self.denom // reduce

#When testing the GCD of a certain fraction create a new one like (x = Fraction) with no parameters. Then invoke the method with (x.gcd(a,b))..
#This will find the greatest common denominator 
def gcd(a,b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a

# necessary to define so that it is usable on hashable
# collections like set, dict, etc..
def __hash__(self):
    '''' returns the hash of the fraction equivalent to
    the hash of the floating point number the fraction represents.
    '''
    return hash(self.numer/self.denom) # use hash of floating point equiv.

# comparison operators

def __lt__(self,other):
    ''' returns True if this fraction is less than the other
    fraction, false otherwise.
    '''
    if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.numer*other.denom < other.numer*self.denom
#Returns true if fracrion is less or equal to other fraction and false otherwise
def __le__(self,other):
    ''' returns True if this fraction is less than or equal
    to the other fraction, false otherwise.
    '''
    if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.numer*other.denom <= other.numer*self.denom
#Tests if one fraction is equal to the other
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.numer*other.denom == other.numer*self.denom
#Tests if on fraction is not equal to the other
def __ne__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
        return NotImplemented
    return self.numer*other.denom != other.numer*self.denom
#Return true if fraction is greater than other fraction.. If not it will return false
def __gt__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
        return False
    return self.numer*other.denom > other.numer*self.denom 
#Returns true if the fraction is less than or equal to fraction and false if it is not
def __ge__(self, other):
     if not isinstance(other,Fraction):
         return NotImplemented
     return self.numer*other.denom >= other.numer*self.denom
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn the `int` into a `Fraction` with the same denominator and then compare them.

Comment: so other can be anything? or does other mean other object. Because I'm trying to figure out if the in the parameters I need to give something to hold a integer

Comment: `other` is always the other object in the comparison.

Comment: I am also unsure how to create an absolute value method for a fraction

Comment: Erm... make sure both numerator and denominator are positive.